# CSS animation with different transition off :hover

Tags: css, hover

I'm working with CSS animations where I'm trying a get a div to bounce out when hovered over (change from `opacity: 0;` to 1). However, when the mouse hovers I want it to fade opacity back to its original value of 0. So far I have:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bouncey {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;  
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: bouncey 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xhuuq/

This successfully applies the bounce out animation when hovered over, but I'm unsure as how to make the div fade back to 0 on mouseleave. Would add `-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;` somewhere help?

I would prefer a css only / non js/jquery solution if it's even possible.

Comment: like this?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xhuuq/5/)

Comment: Tweaked it a little: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DxWz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xhuuq/7/

```
.box{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

transition only happens on blur

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can let `animation` handle the bounce, and then use `transition` to handle the opacity change:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/Xhuuq/9/

```
@-webkit-keyframes bouncey {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: bouncey 1s ease-in-out;
}
```